# Calculation of hash value of a matrix

Tags: cryptography

As part of my final year project, I am testing the Bouncycastle library on SHA-3.
I have found the source code to calculate the hash value of a string:

```
String input = "hello" ;
    SHA3.DigestSHA3 digestSHA3 = new SHA3.Digest256();   
    byte[] digest = digestSHA3.digest(input.getBytes());   
    System.out.println("SHA3-256 = " + Hex.toHexString(digest));
```

but i want to calculate the hash value of a matrix, Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: You just need to convert your matrix to byte array in some way, or to string. And then calculate hash. We don't know what your matrix is, and what will be the purpose of this hash.

Comment: matrix of integer , i will use the hash value for determine the parameter of 1D Logistic map.
you can give me a code to convert matrix to byte array

Comment: How is your matrix specified in code? Is this 2-dimentional array?

Comment: Hashes are computed over bytes, nothing else. You need to define a way to turn your matrix into bytes (ideally in a way you could then turn back to “the same” matrix), then hash that. Note that to hash “a string” you turned it into bytes first.

Comment: yes 2-dimentional array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uniquely convert matrix to byte array. One of the possible solutions:

```
private static byte[] intToBytes(int value) {
    return new byte[] {
        (byte)(value >>> 24),
        (byte)(value >>> 16),
        (byte)(value >>> 8),
        (byte)value
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[][] matrix = new int[3][5];

    SHA3.DigestSHA3 sha3 = new SHA3.Digest256();
    int height = matrix.length;
    int width = matrix[0].length;
    sha3.update(intToBytes(height)); // add height of the matrix
    sha3.update(intToBytes(width));  // add width
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            sha3.update(intToBytes(matrix[i][j])); // add all values
        }
    }

    byte[] digest = digest.digest();
}
```